# Dateformat webix datatable filter

Tags: webix

In my webix table, i try to use the daterange filter.

Without filter:

[image]

Filter:

[image]

I don't know why the filter is not working. There is the same format.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve the problem is to use the`map` function of the date.